# Jenkins Pipeline from SCM. Can we select branch

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

We have our pipelines groovy scripts for Jenkins in SCM (git). I believe it currently gets the scripts from master as default.
Are we able to specify the branch we want to use for the groovy scripts?
There is a setting in the particular section but that seems to be for build branch if I understand correctly (as it allows for setting of multiple branches)

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the branch option is the branch for the pipeline script.

I assume that multiple branches means you can run multiple branches of the different versions of that script. I suspect I am missing when that would be used but it does answer my original question.